# t-sql stored procedure optional var char parameter not working as expected

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I am building a stored procedure to return a list of jobs based on a query from another db. This filter has 1 required parameter that will always be passed and multiple optional parameters that might not necessarily be passed. There is 4 optional parameters and 3 of these I have working as expected; date added, status and allocation. my 'team' parameter is not working as expected. Right now when not passing a team parameter, it only returns all of the jobs that have the 'team' field populated and ignores any without the team property set. I need it to return all jobs in this scenario and not omit any.

To facilitate the optional parameters this I have done the following ;

```
    IF(@allocation='')
    SET @allocation = '%'
```

And it is called in the where clause as;

```
    tbl_PN_jobs.JOB_Name LIKE @allocation
```

This is working for the 3 aforementioned optional parameters but not the 'team' parameter. I have also tried building up a string to use in the where clause based on what parameter is passed, and then appending the string on at the end of the where statements.

```
    if @team Is NUll OR @team = ''
    SET @teamWhere = ''
    ELSE if @team Is NOT NUll OR @team <> ''
    SET @teamWhere =  ' AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = ' 
    + @team


    WHERE
    -- filter
    tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_cando = 1          AND 
    tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_empno = @required_empno      AND                                 
    tbl_PN_Jobs.Job_Status = @Jobstatus  AND
    tbl_PN_jobs.JOB_Name LIKE @allocation AND
    CONVERT(date,tbl_PN_Jobs.JOB_Added,103) LIKE @dateAdded 
    + @teamWhere
```

This returns the full job list as expected when no team parameter is passed but returns 0 jobs when a team is passed.

I expect a data set of 'jobs' under a certain 'team' when that team is passed and for the whole job list to be returned when no 'team' is passed.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Edit full proc below

```
USE [diamond]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_FilterJobs]    Script Date: 31/07/2019 09:10:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <NM & OB>
-- Create date: <2019-06-20>
-- Description: <Returns jobs of type that can be processed by agent>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FilterJobs] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @required_empno INT,
    @Jobstatus NVarchar(20),
    @team varchar(20),  
    @dateAdded nvarchar(max),  --from
    @allocation NvarChar(max)

AS
BEGIN

IF @Jobstatus =''
SET @Jobstatus = 'Active'

Declare @teamWhere As varchar

if @team Is NUll OR @team = ''
SET @teamWhere = ''
ELSE if @team Is NOT NUll OR @team <> ''
SET @teamWhere =  ' AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = ' + @team


if  @team = ''
SET @team = '%'

IF(@allocation= '')
SET @allocation = '%'

If @dateAdded = ''
SET @dateAdded = '%'
ELSE
SET @dateAdded = CONVERT(DATE,CAST(@dateAdded AS smalldatetime),103)

SELECT
tbl_structure_staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team,
tbl_structure_staff_hierarchy.shy_LogonID,
tbl_PN_jobs.*, 
tbl_PN_Job_types.Job_Green, 
tbl_PN_Job_types.Job_Amber, 
tbl_PN_Job_types.Job_Red, 
tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_cando, 
tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_empno, 
TBL_PN_MEMBERS.mem_COMPANY, 
TBL_PN_MEMBERS.mem_nfd,

DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getDate()) AS [MinutesOnly1],
(IIf(DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getdate())>[Job_red],'RED',
IIf(DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getdate())>[Job_amber],'Amber',
IIf(DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getdate())>[job_green],'Green','Blue'))))  AS Colour,
Round(CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getdate()) AS decimal(18,2))/[job_red],2) AS [%ToRed]

FROM
COMPASS_SERVER.compass.dbo.tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy RIGHT JOIN
tbl_PN_jobs LEFT JOIN tbl_PN_Job_types (NOLOCK) ON tbl_PN_jobs.JOB_Name = tbl_PN_Job_types.JOB_type INNER JOIN tbl_PN_staffjobs (NOLOCK) ON tbl_PN_Job_types.JOB_type = tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_JOB_type
LEFT JOIN TBL_PN_MEMBERS (NOLOCK) ON tbl_PN_jobs.JOB_memberNo = tbl_PN_Members.mem_ID ON tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_LogonID = tbl_PN_jobs.Job_Allocate 

WHERE
-- filter
tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_cando = 1          AND 
tbl_PN_staffjobs.stf_empno = @required_empno      AND                                 
tbl_PN_Jobs.Job_Status = @Jobstatus  AND
tbl_PN_jobs.JOB_Name LIKE @allocation AND
CONVERT(date,tbl_PN_Jobs.JOB_Added,103) LIKE @dateAdded 
AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = coalesce(nullif(@team, ''), tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team) 
--+ @teamWhere

--AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team LIKE @team
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(minute, Job_added, getdate()) DESC

OPTION (RECOMPILE)

--AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = CASE When @team = Null OR @team = '' Then '' ELSE @team END
END
```

Calling code; (it's actually a passthrough from an access DB but currently just testing it on SSMS.

```
USE [diamond]
GO

DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @required_empno int
DECLARE @Jobstatus nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @team varchar(20)
DECLARE @dateAdded nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @allocation nvarchar(max)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_FilterJobs] 
   @required_empno = 52469
  ,@Jobstatus = 'active'
  ,@team = 'topas'
  ,@dateAdded = ''
  ,@allocation = ''
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to build dynamic query. That won't work.

Try just to add

```
AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = coalesce(nullif(@team, ''),tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team)
```

This will filter by team only if @team is not null or empty.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help,

So I have just tried this and it works for passing a team but still does the same thing, returning no jobs when no team is passed.

Comment: That means that @team is not null and not ''. Can you check it? Or provide full query and procedure call sample.

Comment: Ok I will add the full proc and the call in a new comment bare with me. Thanks

Comment: owen, please show the call "...when no team is passed..." You can also try CASE like this:...`AND tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team = CASE When @team = Null OR @team = '' Then  tbl_Structure_Staff_hierarchy.shy_csc_team ELSE @team END`

Answer (score 0):

Long way round solution but works; split in to 2 queries, if team is populated run with team filter if team is null then no team filter. Thanks.